# Checkbox jQuery manipulations

Tags: jquery

I am trying to manipulate a series of check-boxes on button click but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I need to achieve the following actions:

1. Select all checkboxes
2. Select checkboxes 1-12
3. Select odd checkboxes
4. Select even checkboxes
5. Clear checkboxes
6. Control slider range to select weeks

All while updating the checkbox.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dYsg7/

Initially I was using the following code to satisfy points 1-5 but as I've changed the layout of my checkboxes I can't figure out how to implement it into my new design:

```
   $('#week_none').click(function () {
        $('#week_boxesForm li').each(function (index) {
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        });
    });

    $('#week_all').click(function () {
        $('#week_boxesForm li').each(function (index) {
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
        });
    });

    $('#week_term').click(function () {
        $('#week_boxesForm li').each(function (index) {
            if (index < 12) $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
            else $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        });
    });

    $('#week_odd').click(function () {
        $('#week_boxesForm li').each(function (index) {
            if (index % 2 === 0) $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
            else $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        });
    });

    $('#week_even').click(function () {
        $('#week_boxesForm li').each(function (index) {
            if (index % 2 !== 0) $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
            else $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do points 1 - 6:

**Javascript**

```
$(".slider_weekRange2").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 15,
    step: 1,
    values: [1, 12],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".search_weekRange2").val(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
        $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
        $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').slice(ui.values[0] - 1, ui.values[1]).prop("checked", true);
    }
});

$(".search_weekRange2").val($(".slider_weekRange2").slider("values", 0) +
    "-" + $(".slider_weekRange2").slider("values", 1));

$('.week_none').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
});

$('.week_all').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", true);
});

$('.week_term').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').slice(0, 12).prop("checked", true);
});

$('.week_odd').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]:even').prop("checked", true);
});

$('.week_even').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]:odd').prop("checked", true);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dYsg7/3/)**

Comment: Would it be possible to update the text box when the buttons are pressed?

Comment: Yes, by putting the following in each on click funtion: `$(".search_weekRange2").val('UPDATE TEXT HERE');`